# Testing for an item in inventory with custom name

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do i test for a item with a name in a players inventory?
Like an identity card for each player that has to verify correctly to open the doors.

Answer (score 3):

The following will test for a piece of paper renamed to "Card" in the player's inventory:

```
/testfor @a {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:paper",tag:{display:{Name:"Card"}}}]}
```

---

If you want to keep track of who has the card (to select them later), you can give players with the card a tag based on the NBT test:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a remove HasCard
/scoreboard players tag @a add HasCard {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:paper",tag:{display:{Name:"Card"}}}]}
```

Running the above commands on a clock in that order will allow you to select people with the card with `@a[tag=HasCard]`.

---

You can read about the NBT format for players and items on this wiki page:
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format