# How do I test for a named item in a players inventory? (Minecraft 1.13)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I'm trying to make a command that tests for a named item in a players inventory, and executes if they have that item. I know that you can test for an item type, but how do I make it test for a name too? Please bear in mind: **I am trying to figure this out for Minecraft 1.13, not any previous versions.**

*Edit: I have already tried this command with no success:

`execute at @a[nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:blaze_rod",Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Doomstick\"}"}}}]}] run say hi`

Edit 2: So after some testing I think it has to do with the attribute modifiers or text color I'm using with the name. Any ideas?

Comment: Please search before asking or at least look at the question list on the right. The first question there already answers this.

Comment: @FabianRöling I removed my comment about this possible dupe. It seems OP is trying to test for every item in a player's inventory instead of the held item.

Comment: Sure, but it works the same, just `Inventory:[]` instead of `SelectedItem:`.

Comment: @FabianRöling That seems like a material difference to me considering the accepted answer there will straight up not work here.

Comment: @Unionhawk He only added the JSON formatting and the example command after I voted to close, everything else is the same as in the other question (except `Count`, but it's not necessarily needed if it doesn't matter how many items there are).

Comment: @FabianRöling `SelectedItem` is still not `Inventory`. "Held item" is a different issue. We may *have a duplicate*, but "how do I test for an item in a player's hand" is not it. As such I am voting to reopen.

Comment: The closer match here would be https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/286927/testing-for-an-item-in-inventory-with-custom-name

Comment: @Unionhawk As of Minecraft 1.13 the top answer for that question is incorrect because `testfor` has been removed and `scoreboard players tag` has been changed to `tag`, therefore it is not a duplicate because Warloch is specifically asking about Minecraft 1.13.

Comment: @Pharap The question currently has 0 dupe votes, but either way good call

Answer (score 6):

So, after a few hours of debugging and fruitless research, I realized that:
**a:** My conjecture in Edit 2 about text format was correct,
and
**b:** it can be solved by including the other text json like so (Please pardon any errors in my json format):

```
execute at @a[nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:blaze_rod",Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Doomstick\",\"color\":\"dark_red\",\"bold\":\"true\",\"italic\":\"true\"}"}}}]}] run say hi
```

Hopefully this helped anyone out there experiencing a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
execute as @a if entity @s[nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:emerald",Count:3b}]}]
```

Just change "Emerald" to whwatever item you want, and you can change "3" to the amount of items you're looking for. That should work for Minecraft 1.13+. I'm currently on Minecraft 1.14.3 Java Edition.

Answer (score 0):

Just Figured the problem out with enchanted items. It doesn't work up until 1.14.4 yet, but I found a solution, easier faster, and better.

```
/give @p minecraft:red_banner{D2Quest1Item:1b,display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Red Flag\"}"},Unbreakable:1,Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:binding_curse",lvl:1}]} 1

/execute if entity @a[distance=..3,gamemode=adventure,team=Blue,nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:red_banner",tag:{D2Quest1Item:1b}}]}]
```

This just adds a custom tag, which is easily detected by the command block.

Answer (score 0):

`/execute as @a if entity @s[nbt={inventory:[{id:"minecraft:<name>"}]}]` would do the trick for computer users

`/execute as @a if entity @s[nbt={inventory:[{id:"<name>"}]}]`    i think would work for mobile users(pe edition)

Comment: didnt work: execute as @a[nbt={inventory:[{id:"minecraft:dried_kelp"}]}] run say hi

Comment: this did: execute as @a[nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:chicken_spawn_egg"}]}] run say hi